# How To Draw Polygon/Rectangle In TChart

Tags: delphi, teechart

I just need a little push.  I have a chart with a series as a tpointseries.  I am having difficultly in figuring out how to draw  the series as a polygon/rectangle.

When I mean polygon or rectangular, you have 4 corners (bottom_left X/Y, top_left X/Y, top_right X/Y and bottom_right XY) which create 4 lines and fill the area between those 4 corners.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Sorry, guess I did not make myself clear.  See my edited question.

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about Column Graph type? Or is it something different that you want. Posting a screenshot or a image mockup of desired graph look would be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

1) Create series of TChartShape type with rectangle style and add shape with needed coordinates

2) Draw rectangle on chart canvas in OnAfterDraw event handler