# How to draw multiple rectangles using the given coordinates in the chart

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, teechart

I have X / Y coordinates stored in a file:

```
1A  0,2770  0,2570
1B  0,2870  0,2730
1C  0,2950  0,2680
1D  0,2850  0,2520
2A  0,2870  0,2730
2B  0,2970  0,2890
2C  0,3050  0,2840
2D  0,2950  0,2680
...
```

The coordinates are read out and stored in an array:

```
type
  TXYPoint = record
    name: string;
    X: double;
    Y: double;
  end;

var
    XYPointList: array of TXYPoint;
```

I try to display the rectangles in the TeeChart Standard 4.04 with Delphi 7 from these coordinates,
in order to be able to tell whether a measuring point lies in this range.

How can I draw multiple rectangles using the given coordinates in the chart?
The help from:
[How To Draw Polygon/Rectangle In TChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145683/how-to-draw-polygon-rectangle-in-tchart) doesn't work or I do anything wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Meanwhile I have the following:

```
function GetChartSeries(von, bis : integer): TLineSeries;
var
    i: integer;
begin
    result:= TLineSeries.Create(nil);
  for i:= von to bis do
  begin
    result.AddXY(XYPointList[i].X,XYPointList[i].Y);
  end;
end;
```

and

```
 l:= Length(XYPointList);
  SetLength(s1,l);

  for i:= 0 to l- 2 do
  begin
    s1[i]:= TLineSeries. Create (nil);
    s1[i].ParentChart:= Chart1;
    s1[i].Assign(GetChartSeries(i,i+1));

  end;
```

But the picture isn't good...[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var 
   s1: array of TLineSeries;
begin
  l:= Length(XYPointList);
  SetLength(s1,l);
  z:= 0;
  for i:= 0 to l-2 do
  begin

    s1[i]:= TLineSeries. Create (nil);
    s1[i].ParentChart:= Chart1;
    if z < 3 then
    begin
        s1[i].Assign(GetChartSeries(i,i+1));
      inc(z);
    end else
    begin
      s1[i].Assign(GetChartSeries(i-2,i+1-2));
      z:=0;
    end;

  end;
```

The function `GetChartSeries` Is described above in the question.